# Auto-incrementing column in ksqlDB?

Tags: ksqldb

I'm currently using [this process](https://gist.github.com/panasenco/2e2f0c846c9d40dd8350da57385c8d59) (see below) to generate an auto-incrementing column in ksqlDB. But now I'm wondering if there are race conditions or other synchronization problems with this approach. Is this a good way to generate an auto-incrementing column in ksqlDB? If not, is there a better way?

> Suppose you want to insert values from one ksqlDB stream into another while auto-incrementing some integer value in the
>   destination stream.
>
> First, create the two streams:
>
> ```
> CREATE STREAM dest (ROWKEY INT KEY, i INT, x INT) WITH (kafka_topic='test_dest', value_format='json', partitions=1);
> CREATE STREAM src (x INT) WITH (kafka_topic='test_src', value_format='json', partitions=1);
> ```
>
> Next, create a materialized view that will contain the maximum value of the destination stream.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE dest_maxi AS SELECT MAX(i) AS i FROM dest GROUP BY 1;
> ```
>
> We need to be able to join the source stream to the materialized view. To do so, we'll create another intermediate stream
>   with a dummy `one` column that's always set to 1, which is what we grouped the materialized view on:
>
> ```
> CREATE STREAM src_one AS SELECT x, 1 AS one FROM src;
> INSERT INTO dest SELECT COALESCE(dest_maxi.i,0)+1 AS i, src_one.x AS x FROM src_one LEFT JOIN dest_maxi ON src_one.one = dest_maxi.ROWKEY PARTITION BY COALESCE(dest_maxi.i,0)+1 EMIT CHANGES;
> ```
>
> Now you can insert values into stream `src` and watch them come up in stream `dest` with auto-incrementing IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach will work. kslqDB offers no guarantees in the order in which is processes records across two different queries. In your case that means no ordering guarantees that

```
CREATE TABLE dest_maxi AS <query>;
```

Will run and update `dest_maxi` before

```
INSERT INTO dest <query>;
```

Runs. Hence, I think you'll run into issues.

It looks like you're trying to take a stream of numbers, e.g.

```
1234
24746
24848
4947
34
```

And add an auto-incrementing id column so that the result looks like:

```
1, 1234
2, 24746
3, 24848
4, 4947
5, 34
```

Something like this should give you what you want:

```
-- source stream of numbers:
CREATE STREAM src (
     x INT
  ) WITH (
    kafka_topic='test_src', 
    value_format='json'
  );

-- intermediate 'table' of numbers and current count:
CREATE TABLE with_counter 
   WITH (partitions = 1) AS
   SELECT
      1 as k,
      LATEST_BY_OFFSET(x) as x,
      COUNT(1) AS id
   FROM src
   GROUP BY 1


-- if you need this back as a stream in ksqlDB you can run:
CREATE STREAM dest (
     x INT,
     id BIGINT
   ) WITH (
     kafka_topic='WITH_COUNTER',
     value_format='json'
   );
```

UDAFs calculate values per-key, hence we group-by a constant, ensuring all input rows are funnelled into a single key (and partition - so this doesn't scale well!).

We use `COUNT` to count the number of rows seen, so its output auto-incrementing, and we use `LATEST_BY_OFFSET` to grab the current value of `x` into our table.

The changelog of the `with_counter` table will then contain the output you want, only with a constant key of `1`:

```
1 -> 1, 1234
1 -> 2, 24746
1 -> 3, 24848
1 -> 4, 4947
1 -> 5, 34
```

We re-import this into ksqlDB as the `dest` stream.  Which you can use as normal.  If you want a topic without the key you can just run:

```
CREATE STREAM without_key AS SELECT * FROM dest;
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew! This is brilliant, and makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This will get duplicated ID if table record got tombstone.